# How to calculate a value based on the previous row's value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Having the following fields in a table...

```
+---------+---+---+
| myTime  | x | y |
+---------+---+---+
|  13:00  | 0 | 0 |
|  13:05  | 2 | 1 |
|  13:10  | 4 | 2 |
|  13:15  | 1 | 3 |
+---------+---+---+
```

I need to generate a third one (z) as follows...

```
+---------+---+---+---+
| myTime  | x | y | z |
+---------+---+---+---+
|  13:00  | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  13:05  | 2 | 1 | 1 |
|  13:10  | 4 | 2 | 3 |
|  13:15  | 1 | 3 | 1 |
+---------+---+---+---+
```

In the first row z will have a value of 0 and in the next ones, z will be calculated as x-y + (previous row's) z.

I've tried using the row number for each record and LAG to try reading values from previous rows...

```
WITH rows_sorted AS  
      (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myTime) AS row_num       
       FROM table) 
       
SELECT myTime, x, y
       IF(row_num = 1, 0, x - y + LAG(z, 1) OVER (ORDER BY row_num)) AS z
FROM rows_sorted
ORDER BY row_num
```

...but evidently wouldn't work as in LAG(z, 1), z has not been generated yet.

Any suggestion on how such a thing can be done? I'm using standard SQL in Google BigQuery

Thanks in advance

---

Since the text above oversimplifies the real calculation, here's a closer approach to what I need to achieve:

```
+---------+----+----+----+
| myTime  |  x |  y |  z |
+---------+----+----+----+
|  13:00  | 15 | 22 |  0 |
|  13:05  |  7 | 21 |  0 |
|  13:10  |  7 |  5 |  2 |
|  13:15  |  9 | 16 |  0 |
|  13:20  | 14 |  5 |  9 |
+---------+----+----+----+
```

Where z for each row is calculated as follows:

- WHEN  row_number() = 1  THEN  z = 0  (already achieved thanks to the
  answer below)
- WHEN  x+(previous row's)z < y  THEN  z = 0
- WHEN  x+(previous row's)z >= y  THEN  z = x+(previous row's)z - y

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . You can get what you want using:

```
select t.*,
       sum(x - y) over (order by mytime) as z
from t;
```

The first row has values of `0` for all the columns, so this works for your sample data.  If you wanted to explicitly set it to `0`, then:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over order by mytime) = 1
             then 0
             else sum(x - y) over (order by mytime) - first_value(x - y) over (order by mytime)
        end) as z
from t;
```

This subtracts out the value from the first row from the cumulative sum.  However, that seems unnecessary.

Comment: First of all thanks so much for your reply. Your response works perfectly for the example I posted, but I just realized I oversimplified the real calculation. Only for the first row (no matter what x and y are) z will always be 0 to 'initialize' z's calculation. From the next row on, if x+(previous row's) z < y then z's value for the current row will be x-y + (previous row's) z, otherwise the value of z will be 0. The value of z on each row will always depend on the previous row's z value, therefore I'm initializing it with 0 in the first row. Any suggestion for this one?

Comment: @iose2t . . . The second version of the query does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: The second version doesn't seem to differentiate between the case when x + prev_z > y (in which case, the calculation of current z would be z = x+prev_ z - y ) AND the case when x + prev_z <= y (in which case should retrieve always z = 0). This second case is never captured. Apologies, in the previous comment I posted the if statement the other way around...